# Simulating a click on React with Enzyme not doing anything

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have a React component class that I'm trying to test clicking behavior on, but for the life of me I can't get the simulation to actually run. Here is the component class:

```
class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavbarWrapper expand={this.props.expand}>
        <NavbarBrand>{logo}</NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} collapsed={!this.state.isOpen}>
          <NavbarIconBar className="top-bar" />
          <NavbarIconBar className="middle-bar" />
          <NavbarIconBar className="bottom-bar" />
        </NavbarToggler>
        <NavbarCollapsibleContent isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          {this.props.children}
        </NavbarCollapsibleContent>
      </NavbarWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the test:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Navbar {...props} />);
const toggler = wrapper.find(NavbarToggler);
const content = wrapper.find(NavbarCollapsibleContent);

// initial state
expect(content.props().isOpen).toBe(false);

// click to expand (i.e. NOT collapse)
toggler.simulate("click");
expect(content.props().isOpen).toBe(true);

// click to collapse
toggler.simulate("click");
expect(content.props().isOpen).toBe(false);
```

Since the initial state of the component's `isOpen` attribute is `false`, the first expect statement runs successfully. However, the second test fails  with the console output:

```
  ● Navbar › should toggle 'NavbarCollapsibleContent's 'isOpen' state when clicking on 'NavbarToggler'

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false
```

which seems to be implying that the simulation didn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to put wrapper.update() between click simulation and expect?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help by itself, but I figured out that the issue seems to be stemming from the `const` declaration at the top of the test, since it was referring to an old version `content`. Replacing `content` with the full `wrapper.find(NavbarCollapsibleContent)` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was being caused from referring to the existing `const content` created at the top of the test, which became stale after the update. Changing the test suite to:

```
const wrapper = shallowTestComponent();
const toggler = wrapper.find(NavbarToggler);

// initial state
expect(wrapper.find(NavbarCollapsibleContent).props().isOpen).toBe(false);

// click to expand (i.e. NOT collapse)
toggler.simulate("click");
expect(wrapper.find(NavbarCollapsibleContent).props().isOpen).toBe(true);

// click to collapse
toggler.simulate("click");
expect(wrapper.find(NavbarCollapsibleContent).props().isOpen).toBe(false);
```

fixed my problem.